# I want to save textbox to .txt file in HTML using JavaScript but I have an error

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fake web site for a school project and I want to get the HTML code to send the information from textbox to .txt file with Javascript, but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Can you tell me where the error is, please?

```
<section>
    <form method:"POST">
        <label>Escrigui el seu usuari:</label>
        <input type="text" name="usuari" id="usuari" size="20"/>
        <label>Escrigui la seva contrasenya:</label>
        <input type="text" name="contrasenya" id="contrasenya" size="20"/>
        <input type="button" value="submit" id="button" href="" onclick="WriteToFile()"/>
    </form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function WriteToFile(passForm){

         set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
         set s   = fso.CreateTextFile("filename.txt", True);

         var usuari = document.getElementById("usuari").value;
         var contrasenya  = document.getElementById("contrasenya").value;

        s.writeline("usuari :" + usuari);
        s.writeline("contrasenya :" + contrasenya);

        s.writeline("-----------------------------");
        s.Close();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: FileSystemObject is not supported by any modern browser. You can only use it in certain pages in Internet Explorer in compatibility mode with deliberately reduced security settings which are fully blocked. Instead, use the new Blob API to generate files that can be saved from within client script. It also looks like you're mixing VBScript with JavaScript in your posting.

Comment: I think you can have a look at this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry. Keep in mind the compatibility issues mentioned by @Dai.

Answer (score 0):

I've programmed a "Notebook" that exports the input to a txt file which is ready to be downloaded after:

```html
<html><head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0%;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "CG";
        src: url(./resources/CENTURYGOTHIC.ttf) format("truetype");
    }

    textarea {
        margin-left: 0%;
        margin-top: 0%;
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
        resize: none;
        visibility: visible;
        background-color: white;
        border-color: black;

    }

    button {
        background-color: white;
        font-family: CG;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

</style></head>


<body>
    <textarea id="textbox" placeholder="You can write anything here... just start tyipng what you would like to remember: Notes, Homework, Tests, just anything."></textarea>
    <button id="create">SAVE TO FILE</button>
    <a download="notes.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none"><button onclick="functionreset()">DOWNLOAD</button></a>
    <br>

    <script>
        (function() {
            var textFile = null,
                makeTextFile = function(text) {
                    var data = new Blob([text], {
                        type: 'text/plain'
                    });

                    // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
                    // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
                    if (textFile !== null) {
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
                    }

                    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

                    return textFile;
                };


            var create = document.getElementById('create'),
                textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

            create.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
                link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
                link.style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('create').style.display = 'none';
            }, false);
        })();

        function functionreset() {
            var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
            link.style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('create').style.display = 'block';
        }

    </script>
    <script>
         document.getElementById("textbox").onchange = function() {functionreset()}
    </script>

<!-- <iframe height=100% width=100%; src=./test.html></iframe>-->
</body></html>
```

maybe you can use fragments of this...

Notify me if it worked

Comment: It didn't work. At the end I decided to change my Javascript for PHP.